# Dockerfile with angular and nginx fails at the build phase

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, npm

I'm trying to build a docker image for my project with angular and nginx, but I get the following errors at the build phase when trying to mount the image (install seems to work fine):

```
#11 103.1 Error: src/app/models/index.ts:5:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputField' or its corresponding type declarations.
#11 103.1
#11 103.1 5 export { InputField } from './inputField';
#11 103.1                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#11 103.1
#11 103.1
#11 103.1
#11 103.1 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#11 103.1 npm ERR! errno 1
#11 103.2 npm ERR! myproject@11.0.0 build: `ng build --build-optimizer --output-hashing=none`
#11 103.2 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#11 103.2 npm ERR!
#11 103.2 npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@11.0.0 build script.
#11 103.2 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#11 103.2
#11 103.2 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#11 103.2 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-17T10_12_55_066Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

My dockerfile:

```
# Angular image
FROM node:latest as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build

# Nginx image
FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=build /dist/angular/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80
```

I've done npm audit fix to solve a couple issues and I've deleted node_modules folder, cache and package-lock.json, and installed again, but none of that seems to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after `RUN npm install` copy over everything to you work dir `COPY . .`

Comment: According to the output the problem is `inputField` what is it? Do you have that file locally?

Comment: @JasonWhite if you not COPY before then npm install will not find the package.json as /app dir will be empty

Comment: InputField is a normal .ts class located with the other models. That specific line comes from index.ts

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file; if so, what's in it?  If you comment out everything after the `RUN npm install` and `docker run --rm ... bash` the resulting image, are your source files there?

Comment: @David Maze Yes, in the .dockerignore I have /node_modules /e2e and .gitignore. And, when I do what you said, yes, in the resulting image my files are there.

Comment: Have you tried after issuing a command `docker run --rm -it <name_of_image> /bin/bash` to execute `npm run build` this will build your app inside the container

Comment: @robert It throws the same error when I try to build it inside the container.

Comment: can you do `ls` on `/app` folder? do you have there that missing file (inputField)?

Comment: @robert Yes, it is there.

Comment: is the file there with exact casing `inputField` not `inputfield` ?

Comment: @robert Thank you, that is what was causing all the trouble, the name of that model was "InputField.ts" and it should have been "inputField.ts". After changing that I also had to change the copy command for the nginx image to "COPY --from=build /app/dist/angular /usr/share/nginx/html" and it worked perfectly. If you answer the inputField thing, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the original issue:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputField'
```

Renaming a file from `InputField.ts` to `inputField.ts` solved the problem with the build inside a container.

**Looking inside Build Container:**

Running only a build container was an excellent comment from @David Maze

something like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it <name_of_the_container> /bin/bash
```

this way you can issue a `npm run build` command and see what is happening inside.

What I also recommend is to have a clean `ng new ngApp` as a reference.
If that app can be built then something else is the problem and not the `Dockerfile`.

Sample:

```
# Angular build image
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build


# Nginx image
FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ngApp /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ng build` command locally before building the docker image. It will show the errors. Currently it can't access the `InputField`.

```
export { InputField } from './inputField';
```

Comment: build is running in a first container note `as build`

Comment: ng build doesn't give any errors, it builds correctly, is only in the dockerfile where it fails.
Appart from that, InputField is a normal .ts class located with the other models. That specific line comes from index.ts